# Monogdb find records by comparing two fields of type ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have a query which is working fine when I run it in MongoDB Compass utility:

```
{ $where: "if (this.media && this.media.length > 1 && this.status=='Published') {return this; } "}
```

In the same collection or table I have two more fields createBy and userId

[image]

Now I want to filter records which have different createdBy than userId. I try this:

```
{ $where: "if (this.media && this.media.length > 1 && this.status=='Published' && this.userId != this.createdBy) {return this; } "}
```

And this also:

```
{ $where: "if (this.media && this.media.length > 1 && this.status=='Published' && ObjectId(this.userId) != ObjectId(this.createdBy)) {return this; } "}
```

But none of the above two works. I understand the ObjectId is of type Object and comparing objects with exact same values wont work. Just not getting it how to compare it in mongodb query console.

Comment: What's the version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: @Andyk. I am using v4.0.8. The MongoDB Compass Community version is 1.17.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `.toString()` method  to compare two ObjectIds

try :

```
this.userId.toString()!= this.createdBy.toString()
```

One other alternative would be to use `.equals()`

```
this.userId.equals(this.createdBy)
```

Read more about [.equals()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals) and [.toString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) here.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I was trying it like `ObjectId(this.userId).toString() != ObjectId(this.createdBy).toString()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongodb version >= 3.6, you can try the `$expr` operation as it is faster than `$where`.

To compare `ObjectId`s, you can either use the `.equals()` method or call the `.toString()` on both `ObjectId` for comparison

```
{ $where: "if (this.media && this.media.length > 1 && this.status=='Published' && !this.userId.equals(this.createdBy)) {return this; } "}
```